# Apache showing the static and media file directory

Tags: django, apache, static, digital-ocean, media

I am hosting a django website on digital ocean using the Apache server. And using apache to serve my static and media files. For that I have edited the `000-default.conf` file as follows
`<VirtualHost *:80>

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:war

    Alias /static /var/www/project/staticfiles
    <Directory /var/www/project/staticfiles>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /media /var/www/project/media
    <Directory /var/www/project/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/project/project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess project python-home=/var/www/projenv python-path=/var/www/techshark
    WSGIProcessGroup project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/project/project/wsgi.py


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined`
```

this work fine, but when i visit the ip/static/  or ip/media/ on the browser, it shows the static and media directory to the user which i do not want.
[image]

Can anyone please help me to sever the static and media files without showing all the directory path to the users.

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333705/how-to-disable-directory-indexing-from-apache2-when-going-to-the-servers-root or https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex